# InfluxDB get list of changes

Tags: influxdb

I would like to get a result such as the following:

```
name           from_value      to_value            at 
tag A          10              15                  2019-02-11 16:00
tag B          1               2                   2019-02-11 16:00
tag A          15              20                  2019-02-11 16:05
tag B          2               3                   2019-02-11 16:05
tag A          20              25                  2019-02-11 16:10
tag B          3               4                   2019-02-11 16:10
```

basically a column "from_value" (previous value current point) and a column "to_value" (current value current point).

To select only the current point value I do:

`SELECT value FROM data WHERE "name"='tag A'`

What if I wanted to select also the previous value?

`SELECT prev(value) AS "from_value", value  AS "to_value" FROM data WHERE "name"='tag A'`

Can I do something like the above or I need to always save the previous value every time for every new point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `group by time` you can use `last()` and `difference()` functions to get value changes per time interval.

```
SELECT LAST(value)-DIFFERENCE(LAST(value)) as FromValue, LAST(value) as ToValue
FROM demo where time > 1549983975150000000 
GROUP BY time(10ms),tagA FILL(none)
```

```
name: demo
tags: tagA=1
time                FromValue ToValue
----                --------- -------
1549984410470000000           10
1549984421820000000 10        15
1549984431180000000 15        17
1549984436350000000 17        10
1549984753810000000 10        10
```

```
SELECT * FROM demo
name: demo
time                tagA value
----                ---- -----
1549984410475859753 1     10
1549984421827992234 1     15
1549984431180379398 1     17
1549984436356232522 1     10
1549984753817094214 1     10
```

Comment: Actually the first record now is None/10 and the second 10/15. I would need first record 15/10 second 17/15 and so on...

Comment: Also I would need the resulting list to be a mix of the changes of tagA and tabB not only 1 of them.

Comment: Adjust group by tag part as needed.

Comment: Group by tag returns N groups of result where N is the number of tags I have. I need 1 single mixed list.

Comment: `select * from (select last(value)-difference(last(value)) as FromValue, last(value) as ToValue from demo where time > 1549983975150000000 group by time(10ms),* fill(none))` can be close to what you want.